# The values in for don't save outside of it

Tags: c, dev-c++

I'm assigning a value in a variable within a loop but when i print it the value returns as 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int N=0,sum=0;
int main(){
    for(N=1; sum>200; N=N+1){
        sum= sum + N;
}
printf("the last number added to reach 200 is %d with the sum being %d:", N, sum);   
return 0;
}
```

The variable N when printed is returned as 1 and the variable sum has the value 0 which should be something else

Comment: What else should `sum` be, and why?

Comment: How many iterations will the loop make when the condition to make an iteration is that `sum > 200`?

Comment: around 20 loops i think and sum should be more than 200

Comment: @George Read my question again. What is `sum` when the `for` loop is about to make its first iteration? Is it greater than 200?

Comment: it's less than 200

Comment: @George Ok, it's less than 200, but the condition to make an iteration is that it's greater than 200. `<` means less than and `>` means greater than and in `for(...; condition; ...)` the _condition_ must be `true` for an iteration to be made.

Comment: thanks a lot. I know the simbols meaning but i thought the second slot was something like "continue until sum is greater than 200"

Comment: @George No, the second expression is the condition that must evaluate to `true` for it to make an iteration. See [`for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/for)

Answer (score 1):

The second item in a `for` the is the condition to **continue** the loop. `sum>200` says to continue if `sum` is greater than 200. `sum` starts at zero, so it is not greater than 200, so the loop ends immediately.